# Prove that for some $m,n$ with $1 \le m \le n \le 100$ , $S=\sum_{i=m}^{n} a_i$ is always divisible by $100$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation, divisibility

Let $a_1$,$a_2$, $\cdots$ ,$a_{100}$ be $100$ positive integers. Then  Prove that  for some $m,n$ with $1 \le m \le n \le 100$,   $S=\sum_{i=m}^{n} a_i$ is always divisible by $100$

My Try:

we have $$S=a_m+a_{m+1}+a_{m+2}+\cdots a_n$$

Any integer $a_i$ can be written in the form $a_i=100q_i+r_i$ where $q_i$ is some integer and $0 \le r_i \le 99$  Hence

$$S=100 \sum_{i=m}^{n} q_i+\sum_{i=m}^{n} r_i$$

It suffices to prove that $\exists$ $m,n$ such that $$S_r=\sum_{i=m}^{n} r_i$$ is divisible by $100$ ,$\forall$ $0 \le r_i \le 99$

Any clue?

Comment: Are you asking if for any ordered sequence of positive integers the sum of any number of them is divisible by 100? Because that is false, take $a_i =i$, $m=1, n=4$

Comment: I would reformulate your question to make it more understandable:

"Then you can find $1 \le m \le n \le 100$ such that $$S=\sum_{i=m}^{n} a_i$$ is divisible by $100$"

Comment: Yes i have reformulated accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Work out the sums of the integers:

$a_1$

$a_1+a_2$

$a_1+a_2+a_3$

$\vdots$

$a_1+a_2+\dots+a_{100}$

There are $100$ of these sums. If any one of them is divisible by $100$ we are done.

If not, then the $100$ partial sums have remainders between $1$ and $99$ (inclusive) when divided by $100$. By the pigeonhole principle at least two must have the same remainder.

Suppose these two are the sequences $a_1+\dots+a_{m-1}$ and $a_1+\dots+a_{n}$.

Then their difference is $a_m+\dots+a_n$ and is divisible by $100$.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the numbers modulo $100$:
If $a_1 \equiv 0 \mod{100}$ we are done.
If $a_2 \equiv 0 \mod{100}$ or $a_2 \equiv -a_1 \mod{100}$, then we are done. As we assume that $a_1$ is not already zero, this are two different options.
For $a_3$, we are done if $a_3 \in \{0,-(a_1+a_2),-a_2\} \mod{100}$, and once again, if we weren't done in the previous steps, then these numbers are all different mod 100.

Continuing this way and formalizing the fact that all the excluded numbers are always different as long as we are not finished, we will get that
$$a_{100} \not \in \{0,1,\ldots ,99 \} \mod{100}$$ or we are done. Of course, the first case is not possible.